# Modsecurity block request

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-security

How can I block in modsecurity these requests:
12.54.87.55:443
https://12.54.87.55

tried

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "12.54.87.55:443" phase:1,id:1008,log,deny,status:403
```

but seems like it's not working.
I want to block all the requests where Host header is a numeric IP address

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many examples of rules given in the [ModSecurity Rule Writing Workshop](https://www.feistyduck.com/books/modsecurity-handbook/modsecurity-rule-writing-workshop.pdf):

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "^[\d\.]+$" "phase:1,t:none,block,msg:'Host is an IP address'"
```

Comment: Thanks @fvu
The problem is I have an Apache server with multiple vhosts, and when you request 12.12.12.12:443 apache is redirecting to the first valid ssl cert it finds, before modsecurity does anything. Your code above works only with 80 port.